# How can we call sub flows from another flow Xml?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I have a main flow and there are several sub-flows. I need to call a flow at specific level at activity. Is it possible to do in pace automation framework?

Answer (score 0):

Able to call a flow defined in another flow xml file or to create a master flow for the flows defined in multiple flow xml’s. This would also help PAF users to create a master test suite with multiple flows in it in ALM, SynapseRT etc.
**Tag Name: call**

Attributes:

flow – to specify the flow id xml – to specify the flow xml path in which the flow is defined.

```
Syntax: <call flow="flow_id" xml="flow_xml_path"></call>
```